# How to load a file in Julia without specifying full absolute path?

Tags: file-io, julia

I am trying to run the following script in Julia:

```
open("users/xxx/xxx.txt", "a+") do io
        write(io, "\n\nblah blah blah @ $(function())\blahhhhhh: $(variable)")
end
```

However, if I don't include the absolute path, this doesn't work... I don't want to use the absolute path such that my code will be more general.

Note: blah, variable, and function are used to make my code more general for this question.

Comment: You should be able to use relative paths. Check with `pwd()` wether you are in the correct folder.

Comment: your code is correct, however the directory user/xxx must exist before running it. Most likely you are in other folder than you expect (use `pwd()` to check)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`@__DIR__`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.0/base/file/#Base.@__DIR__) is your friend. To write more general code, you could use `joinpath(@__DIR__, "path", "relative", "to", "the", "script", "file")`. In REPL, `@__DIR__` is `pwd()`.